Null .csv files when extracting node data from .xml files
Trying this again. Ok so I have a powershell script that processes .xml files in a directory. For each .xml file the script processes it is looking for every instance of <AuditRecord> and extracts all data within each node.
The challenge I am having when I try to write results to a .csv file it comes up empty. No headers, no data, absolutely nothing. I've been racking my brain over why it won't simply write the data into the .csv file
Update 07.31.2024: Incorporated recent suggestions. Code sample updated - no errors: but it still generates a .csv file with no headers or data in it (blank)
Update 07.31.2024: Refactored code. This time it doesn't generate any .csv file. This is very discouraging, don't know what to do at this point. I can fix the params to read the elements correctly as suggested, but I can't even generate a simple .csv with content. Any help would be sorely appreciated.
CODE
    cls
    
    $inPath = "C:\deathstar\test\in\"
    $outPath = "C:\deathstar\test\in\"
    
    # Create the 'out' directory if it doesn't exist
    if (-not (Test-Path $outPath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $outPath | Out-Null
    }
    
    # Get all XML files in the 'in' directory
    $xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem $inPath -Filter *.xml
    
    foreach ($file in $xmlFiles) {
        [xml]$xmlContent = Get-Content $file.FullName
    
        $auditRecord = $xmlContent.AuditRecord
    
        if ($auditRecord -ne $null) {
            $outputData = [ordered]@{
                AuditRecordID = $auditRecord.AuditRecordID
                UserID = $auditRecord.PIUser.Name
                UTCSeconds = $auditRecord.PITime.UTCSeconds
                LocalDate = $auditRecord.PITime.LocalDate
                PIModuleAction = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.Action
                PIModuleUID = ($auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.UniqueID -join ", ")
                PIModuleName = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.Name
                PIModuleAttribName = ($auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Name -join ", ")
                PIModValueBefore = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.Before.Type[0]
                PIModValueAfter = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.After.Type[0]
                PIModAttribName = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Name[1]
                PIModAttribValBefore = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.Before.Type[1]
                PIModAttribValAfter = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.After.Type[1]
                PIPropertyName = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Name
                PIPropertyAction = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Action
                PIPropertyUNCName = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.ParentUNC_Name
                PIPropValBefore = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Value.Before.Type
                PIPropertyValAfter = $auditRecord.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Value.After.Type
            }
    
            $csvFileName = "$outPath\$($file.BaseName).csv"
            $outputData | Export-Csv -Path $csvFileName -NoTypeInformation
        }
    }

.XML FILE SNIPPET
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<PIAudit
  xmlns="xml.osisoft.com-schemas-piaudit"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="xml.osisoft.com-schemas-piaudit http://xml.osisoft.com/Schemas/PIAudit">
  <PIServer IPHost="DEATH-STAR" IPAddress="192.168.1.1"/>
  <ExportDate UTCSeconds="1722272370" LocalDate="2024-07-29T12:59:30-04:00"/>
  <OSUser Domain="RX" Name="dvadar" />
  <AuditRecords ExportFileName="C:\Batch\1\input\pibasessAudit.dat3_Apr_24_17_24_10_16502" RecordCount="420" AuditFileName="D:\PI\log\pibasessAudit.dat" CreationDate="2024-03-28T17:47:42-04:00" Mask="ffffffffh">
    <AuditRecord AuditRecordID="b066447a-20de-4659-8e5e-41ecb27d9d39">
      <PIUser UserID="1" Name="piadmin"/>
      <PITime UTCSeconds="1711662501" LocalDate="2024-03-28T17:48:21-04:00" />
      <PIConfigurationDB>
        <PIModules Action="Edit">
          <PIModule UniqueID="feea9e80-3d3f-4f45-b58d-275e4845bcde, 31-Dec-69 16:00:01" Name="Database">
            <PIModuleAttributes>
              <PIModuleAttribute Name="ModifyDate">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:dateTime">2024-03-28T17:47:42-04:00</Before>
                  <After Type="xs:dateTime">2024-03-28T17:48:21-04:00</After>
                </Value>
              </PIModuleAttribute>
              <PIModuleAttribute Name="Revision">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:long">35738</Before>
                  <After Type="xs:long">35739</After>
                </Value>
              </PIModuleAttribute>
            </PIModuleAttributes>
            <PIProperties>
              <PIProperty Name="TemplateDataSet" Action="Edit" ParentUNC_Name="\\PIProperties">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:hexBinary"></Before>
                  <After Type="xs:hexBinary"></After>
                </Value>
              </PIProperty>
            </PIProperties>
          </PIModule>
        </PIModules>
      </PIConfigurationDB>
    </AuditRecord>
    <AuditRecord AuditRecordID="d6588207-7ab2-4a4f-bfba-f62621a2cae2">
      <PIUser UserID="1" Name="piadmin"/>
      <PITime UTCSeconds="1711662705" LocalDate="2024-03-28T17:51:45-04:00" />
      <PIConfigurationDB>
        <PIModules Action="Edit">
          <PIModule UniqueID="feea9e80-3d3f-4f45-b58d-275e4845bcde, 31-Dec-69 16:00:01" Name="Database">
            <PIModuleAttributes>
              <PIModuleAttribute Name="ModifyDate">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:dateTime">2024-03-28T17:48:21-04:00</Before>
                  <After Type="xs:dateTime">2024-03-28T17:51:45-04:00</After>
                </Value>
              </PIModuleAttribute>
              <PIModuleAttribute Name="Revision">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:long">35739</Before>
                  <After Type="xs:long">35740</After>
                </Value>
              </PIModuleAttribute>
            </PIModuleAttributes>
            <PIProperties>
              <PIProperty Name="TemplateDataSet" Action="Edit" ParentUNC_Name="\\PIProperties">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:hexBinary"></Before>
                  <After Type="xs:hexBinary"></After>
                </Value>
              </PIProperty>
            </PIProperties>
          </PIModule>
        </PIModules>
      </PIConfigurationDB>
    </AuditRecord>
    <AuditRecord AuditRecordID="ff041b3b-ca18-4909-a16a-18444d8b17b9">
      <PIUser UserID="1" Name="piadmin"/>
      <PITime UTCSeconds="1711669167" LocalDate="2024-03-28T19:39:27-04:00" />
      <PIConfigurationDB>
        <PIModules Action="Edit">
          <PIModule UniqueID="feea9e80-3d3f-4f45-b58d-275e4845bcde, 31-Dec-69 16:00:01" Name="Database">
            <PIModuleAttributes>
              <PIModuleAttribute Name="ModifyDate">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:dateTime">2024-03-28T17:51:45-04:00</Before>
                  <After Type="xs:dateTime">2024-03-28T19:39:27-04:00</After>
                </Value>
              </PIModuleAttribute>
              <PIModuleAttribute Name="Revision">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:long">35740</Before>
                  <After Type="xs:long">35741</After>
                </Value>
              </PIModuleAttribute>
            </PIModuleAttributes>
            <PIProperties>
              <PIProperty Name="TemplateDataSet" Action="Edit" ParentUNC_Name="\\PIProperties">
                <Value>
                  <Before Type="xs:hexBinary"></Before>
                  <After Type="xs:hexBinary"></After>
                </Value>
              </PIProperty>
            </PIProperties>
          </PIModule>
        </PIModules>
      </PIConfigurationDB>
    </AuditRecord>
  </AuditRecords>
</PIAudit>

DESIRED OUTPUT


Sadly, HTML and XML don't have regular syntax, so regular expressions won't work on them 100%. You could try another approach that will work better with your own data (e.g. BeautifulSoup)

Using regex to parse XML is just nonsense. Use XmlDocument class to extract whatever you need from your Xml. If you add a sample of the expected output it's easier to help.

@SantiagoSquarzon I beg to differ, I was making headway with the regex parser, but it fails at capturing  data. I'm new to this so "XmlDocument class" is chinese to me unless you provide  an example. I rewrote the statement however using .xml approach but still yield a null .csv file. (zero content)

@RafaeldeBem You're right. Trying the regex way came close but breaks for some reason trying to read  strings. I'm trying .xml parsing but I'm in worse position than before I am getting zero records written to .csv

$data += $record is slow.  Better to add to a list.  Not sure why you aren't using my code posted in your previous posting which works.

@NanoNet RegEx only works on regular grammars; HTML and XML aren't regular grammars! That's why they don't work - or sometimes they semi-work but you'll be opening yourself to risk. Always use a parser. Anyway, this isn't really what your question seems to be about hahahah

Updated the Code from my answer to match your new Sample

Consider XSLT, the special-purpose, industry-wide language designed to transform XML files into other XML, HTML, and even text files like CSVs! PowerShell can run XSLT with built-in System.Xml.Xsl or other, third-party XSLT processors (Saxon, Xalan, etc.) which can run higher versions 2.0 and 3.0.
Specifically, below XSLT 1.0 will walk through every descendant element and attribute of root (assumed to be <AuditRecord>) and extracts underlying text values in comma separation. To create unique headers, ancestor elements three levels up are concatenated together with underscore separators. For elements that do not have such ancestor, underscores are stretched out with no values between. Also, some elements do not have any text and hence return empty cells. Consider cleaning this up later on!
XSLT (save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/AuditRecord">
        <!-- HEADERS -->
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/@* | descendant::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(../../..), '_', name(../..), '_', ../@Name, '_', name(..), '_', name())"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- ROWS -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- PARSE ELEMENTS -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- PARSE ATTRIBUTES -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output (CSV shown in markdown table version)
| ___AuditRecord_PIUser | _AuditRecord_piadmin_PIUser_UserID | _AuditRecord_piadmin_PIUser_Name | ___AuditRecord_PITime     | _AuditRecord__PITime_UTCSeconds | _AuditRecord__PITime_LocalDate | ___AuditRecord_PIConfigurationDB     | _AuditRecord__PIConfigurationDB_PIModules | AuditRecord_PIConfigurationDB__PIModules_Action | AuditRecord_PIConfigurationDB__PIModules_PIModule | PIConfigurationDB_PIModules_Database_PIModule_UniqueID | PIConfigurationDB_PIModules_Database_PIModule_Name | PIConfigurationDB_PIModules_Database_PIModule_PIModuleAttributes | PIModules_PIModule__PIModuleAttributes_PIModuleAttribute | PIModule_PIModuleAttributes_ModifyDate_PIModuleAttribute_Name | PIModule_PIModuleAttributes_ModifyDate_PIModuleAttribute_Value | PIModuleAttributes_PIModuleAttribute__Value_Before | PIModuleAttribute_Value__Before_Type | PIModuleAttributes_PIModuleAttribute__Value_After | PIModuleAttribute_Value__After_Type | PIModules_PIModule__PIModuleAttributes_PIModuleAttribute | PIModule_PIModuleAttributes_Revision_PIModuleAttribute_Name | PIModule_PIModuleAttributes_Revision_PIModuleAttribute_Value | PIModuleAttributes_PIModuleAttribute__Value_Before | PIModuleAttribute_Value__Before_Type | PIModuleAttributes_PIModuleAttribute__Value_After | PIModuleAttribute_Value__After_Type | PIConfigurationDB_PIModules_Database_PIModule_PIProperties | PIModules_PIModule__PIProperties_PIProperty | PIModule_PIProperties_TemplateDataSet_PIProperty_Name | PIModule_PIProperties_TemplateDataSet_PIProperty_Action | PIModule_PIProperties_TemplateDataSet_PIProperty_ParentUNC_Name | PIModule_PIProperties_TemplateDataSet_PIProperty_Value | PIProperties_PIProperty__Value_Before | PIProperty_Value__Before_Type | PIProperties_PIProperty__Value_After | PIProperty_Value__After_Type |
|-----------------------|------------------------------------|----------------------------------|---------------------------|---------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|-------------------------------|--------------------------------------|------------------------------|
| 1                     | piadmin                            | 1711662501                       | 2024-03-28T17:48:21-04:00 |                                 | Edit                           | feea9e80-3d3f-4f45-b58d-275e4845bcde | 31-Dec-69 16:00:01                        | Database                                        |                                                   | ModifyDate                                             |                                                    | xs:dateTime2024-03-28T17:47:42-04:00                             | xs:dateTime2024-03-28T17:48:21-04:00                     | Revision                                                      |                                                                | xs:long35738                                       | xs:long35739                         |                                                   | TemplateDataSet                     | Edit                                                     | \\PIProperties                                              |                                                              | xs:hexBinary                                       | xs:hexBinary                         |                                                   |                                     |                                                            |                                             |                                                       |                                                         |                                                                 |                                                        |                                       |                               |                                      |                              |

PowerShell
# Define the directory containing the XML files
$directory = "C:\test\"

# Get all XML files in the directory
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter *.xml

# Load XSLT
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load("C:\path\to\style.xsl");

# Loop through each XML file
foreach ($file in $xmlFiles) {
    # Define the output CSV file path
    $csvFilePath = Join-Path -Path $directory -ChildPath ($file.BaseName + ".csv")

    # Run transformation (XML -> CSV)
    $xslt.Transform($file.FullName, $csvFilePath);
}


Brilliant, absolutely brilliant! Thank you for helping me solution this with a practical application. Not only did it work, but it also solved an issue I ran into where the XML was scaling in terms of before type, and after type. Some of the XML were many children deep, and this solution simply listed all the artifacts under "type". Genius. Huge thanks again

OK so you changed your question a bit and gave a new sample file so i rewrote my answer to reflect your changes.
$Directory = 'C:\Test\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter *.xml | 
    ForEach-Object{
        $CsvFilePath = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + ".csv")
        Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath "//*" | 
        Where-Object{$_.Node.ToString() -eq 'AuditRecord'} | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node |
        ForEach-Object{
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                AuditRecordID = $_.AuditRecordID
                UserID = $_.PIUser.UserID
                UserName = $_.PIUser.Name
                UTCSeconds = $_.PITime.UTCSeconds
                LocalDate = $_.PITime.LocalDate
                PIModuleAction = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.Action
                PIModuleUniqueID = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.UniqueID -join ", "
                PIModuleName = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.Name
                PIModuleAttribName = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Name -join ", "
                DateTimeXSBefore = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.Before.Type[0]
                DateTimeXSAfter = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.After.Type[0]
                PIModuleAttribName2 = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Name[1]
                LongBefore = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.Before.Type[1]
                LongAfter = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.After.Type[1]
                PIModuleAttribName3 = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Name
                PIPropertyName = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Action
                PIPropertyAction = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.ParentUNC_Name
                hexbinBefore = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Value.Before.Type
                hexbinAfter = $_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIProperties.PIProperty.Value.After.Type       
            }
        } | Export-Csv -Path $CsvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
    }

Will result in
"AuditRecordID","UserID","UserName","UTCSeconds","LocalDate","PIModuleAction","PIModuleUniqueID","PIModuleName","PIModuleAttribName","DateTimeXSBefore","DateTimeXSAfter","PIModuleAttribName2","LongBefore","LongAfter","PIModuleAttribName3","PIPropertyName","PIPropertyAction","hexbinBefore","hexbinAfter"
"b066447a-20de-4659-8e5e-41ecb27d9d39","1","piadmin","1711662501","2024-03-28T17:48:21-04:00","Edit","feea9e80-3d3f-4f45-b58d-275e4845bcde, 31-Dec-69 16:00:01","Database","ModifyDate, Revision","xs:dateTime","xs:dateTime","Revision","xs:long","xs:long","TemplateDataSet","Edit","\\PIProperties","xs:hexBinary","xs:hexBinary"
"d6588207-7ab2-4a4f-bfba-f62621a2cae2","1","piadmin","1711662705","2024-03-28T17:51:45-04:00","Edit","feea9e80-3d3f-4f45-b58d-275e4845bcde, 31-Dec-69 16:00:01","Database","ModifyDate, Revision","xs:dateTime","xs:dateTime","Revision","xs:long","xs:long","TemplateDataSet","Edit","\\PIProperties","xs:hexBinary","xs:hexBinary"
"ff041b3b-ca18-4909-a16a-18444d8b17b9","1","piadmin","1711669167","2024-03-28T19:39:27-04:00","Edit","feea9e80-3d3f-4f45-b58d-275e4845bcde, 31-Dec-69 16:00:01","Database","ModifyDate, Revision","xs:dateTime","xs:dateTime","Revision","xs:long","xs:long","TemplateDataSet","Edit","\\PIProperties","xs:hexBinary","xs:hexBinary"

So lets talk about it
First thing some of your XML Paths are slightly wrong
Example
$_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.Before.Type[0]

Returns
xs:dateTime

What you wanted was more like
$_.PIConfigurationDB.PIModules.PIModule.PIModuleAttributes.PIModuleAttribute.Value.Before[0].'#text'

Returns
2024-03-28T17:47:42-04:00

There seems to be a couple that are like that which just need a slightly adjusted path. But i do not have time to fix those right now.
So why did your script not work?
Lets look at a sample of the code
foreach ($auditRecord in $xmlContent.SelectNodes("//AuditRecord")) {
    $record = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        AuditRecordID = AuditRecordID
        UserID = PIUser.UserID
    }
}

I would have expected your code to error out above
You are looping XML //AuditRecord using the var $auditRecord
But when you get into the loop you dont call $auditRecord when setting the value of your PSObject properties.
I would have expected to see was more like
foreach ($auditRecord in $xmlContent.SelectNodes("//AuditRecord")) {
    $record = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        AuditRecordID = $auditRecord.AuditRecordID
        UserID = $auditRecord.PIUser.UserID
    }
}


@ArcSet  This looks truly amazing, and greatly appreciated, but it does not incorporate with my file looping > record reading routine (I'm fairly newly to Powershell and have a challenge following the nuance. When I use it alone (directly from your example it errors with "Error: "This document already has a Document Element Node. Plus the use of "Select-Xml - LiteralyPath $_.FullName" as suggested by mklement0 results in a console prompt asking me where is "Xpath" followed by the "error Select-Xml : Cannot validate argument ... 'XPath'. " It's a bit to unpack, but I'll see how I can fit this.

@ArcSet Seems like the .xml file I had was bad. Replaced it with a viable. xml file however when I run your sample code it still produces an empty .csv file. no headers or data. Ill update my question to reflect a sample of the .xml file and the first 3 iterations so you can see what I'm up against

@ArcSet so I added  the following and notice that $data does appear empty. Still confused as to why when the .xml file does have data clearly, and the tag is set correctly to read parent node "AuditRecord"  if ($data.Count -gt 0) {
$data | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
} else {
Write-Host "No data found in $($file.FullName)"
}

refactored code implementing suggested variables. No .csv file generated :(

Updated my answer for you

This works very well for a fixed .XML block. I discovered some of the XML patterns are pages long as "Before" and "After" Types can appear many times. Not only did I have to figure out how to consume the .xml for processing but scale with the random number of child nodes. Still I upvoted this edit for your tremendous help
